# Would it be possible to run an application right after csrss.exe loads? (Windows)

Tags: windows, winapi

Is it possible to run a win32 application right after csrss.exe loads but before things like winlogon.exe and wininit.exe load?

Comment: You would be better off sharing your ultimate aim.

Comment: What do you mean "aim" I am just wondering if that would be possible

Comment: By "aim", can you explain WHY you would want to do this?  This sounds like a potential security threat to me. In any case, this doesn't sound like a programming question, perhaps try asking on [su] instead.